# Order entries query of a structure by lightswitch field

Tags: craft3

I have a bunch of entries in a structure and I want to have all the "featured" entries returned first. Then everything else returned in the order set for that structure in the admin.

The answer to a similar question ([Order Entries Query by a Featured Light Switch](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35943/order-entries-query-by-a-featured-light-switch)) works well for channels, but not for structures…

```
craft.entries().section('mySection').orderBy('featured DESC').all()
```

☝️ This seems to be defaulting to `postDate` as a "second" parameter, as opposed to "the order defined by the section" like the [documentation seems to indicate](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#orderby) it should do for a structure.

Is this a bug, or is there a way to explicitly order by the structure's ordering in a second parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you've overriden the `orderBy` parameter, you'll need to specify the second thing you want to order by. Structures store order and hierarchy using a few extra properties. You can use the `lft` property to sort the structures entries, meaning that the following code should solve your question.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries
    .section('structure')
    .orderBy({ 'featured': SORT_DESC, 'lft': SORT_ASC })
    .all() 
%}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I find this `lft` property? I was looking all over the docs but couldn't find it… Thanks again!

Comment: You'll find it in the `structureelements` database table, it is likely not documented because it is used internally, along with a few other properties, to store the element's position within the structure.